# Lost Whatsapp messages forever?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup

Regrettably I think I already know the answer to this question, but I thought it good to check just in case!

I deleted and reinstalled Whatsapp, but for some reason unknown to me iCloud hadn't taken a back up since Sept 2020. So of course when I reinstall and restore I realise I've lost a year's worth of media and messages.

Is there anything that can be done or are these messages lost forever? I could have sworn I've swapped phones within the last year and had no problems restoring, even though a back up hadn't been done... So SURELY there must be a way?

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Did you use the device-to-device transfer when you got a new phone? That doesn't require a backup.

Comment: Ahh yes I did, that would be it. Thanks for clarifying!